# Need help finding the title of book about an Aboriginal Australian, found in a cryo-pod on a generation ship, who's psychic

Tags: story-identification

This was a book that I read pre-2008.

It was a (then) 3 part book series with the point of view jumping around 3 different characters (a-la Game of Thrones and Wheel of Time).

It was published by Roc or Tor.

The scene I remembered was that one of the main characters was an Aboriginal Australian, found in a cryo-pod on a generation ship type deal, sold to slavery and then found out that he is psychic. Went to a spy academy. Every psychic in this world could connect to a collective conscious to find answers or secrets.

When he finally connects to the psychic world, it only happens because he figures out how to meditate standing up with a spear behind his back like his ancestors in the Outback communicated through Dreamtime. 
The first psychic image he got was described as massive sky-sweeps of Australia ending at Ayers Rock.

Comment: Game of Thrones (or rather a Song of Ice and Fire) and Wheel of Time have a **LOT** more than 3 viewpoint characters. Just saying. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the *[Silent Empire](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43224-the-silent-empire)* series by Steven Harper. An excerpt from an editorial review of the first book (emphasis mine):

> All sentient minds are connected to a place called **The Dream**, and without them it would cease to exist. Only a small percentage of genetically gifted beings, called the Silent, can consciously access it. Among the Silent is Kendi, a courageous and compassionate man of **Aboriginal descent**. Ominous storms have started to appear in The Dream, leaving dead or nearly dead Silents in their wake.

And, from [someone else looking for the book](http://forums.abebooks.com/discussions/AbeBookscom_BookSleuthreg/Science_Fiction/Dreaming_as_interstellar_communication_slavery_and_a_plot_to_destroy_the_Dream/abesleuthcom/31490.1?mode=simple&redirCnt=1&u=465621152&nav=messages) who confirmed the answer:

> A boy and his family leave Earth on a sub-light speed colony ship in stasis. While they are travelling, technology overtakes them and FTL ships are invented. The **colony ship** is awakened to discover that they have been taken by **slavers** and I believe that the boy and his mother are sold together.

Book covers:
[image: Dreamer] [image: Nightmare] [image: Trickster] [image: Offspring]